# How to find out if an Entity Framework object has changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I've an object which is called `Uczestnik` which just got saved to database

```
var konsultant = uczestnik.Konsultanci; 
uczestnik.Konsultanci = null; // null attached object and reuse it's ID later on for SAVE purposes
uczestnik.KonsultantNazwa = konsultant.KonsultantNazwa;
uczestnik.Szkolenie = null; // null attached object and reuse it's ID later on for SAVE purposes
uczestnik.SzkolenieID = szkolenie.SzkolenieID;                       
context.SzkolenieUczestnicies.AddObject(uczestnik);
context.SaveChanges();
context.Detach(uczestnik); // detatch to prevent Context problems
uczestnik.Szkolenie = szkolenie;// reassign for use in ObjectListView
uczestnik.Konsultanci = konsultant; // reassign for use in ObjectListView
```

After it's saved it's back into ObjectListView where user decided to change some value and the value was changed (one value from multiple to be exact). If I check value's entity state it's in Unchanged state so calling .Attach and .SaveChanges() won't do anything. I can use `ChangeObjectState` but if there's nothing changed then there's no sense to do so.

```
context.SzkolenieUczestnicies.Attach(uczestnik);
//context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(uczestnik, EntityState.Modified);
context.SaveChanges();
```

How can I detect the change and prevent unnecessary traffic (I can imagine situation where nothing is changed in the object that holds files 5mb big) so `resaving` it makes no sense. Unless Entity is smart enough to detect that only one field was changed from 15 and change only that field?

Comment: Have you looked at ObjectContext.DetectChanges?

Comment: No, wasn't aware of it? How would I use it? Also considering that context is enclosed in `using` wouldn't DetectChanges show nothing when it's executed on new context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `Detach` entity it is not tracked by the context. In such case you are responsible for detecting when the object has changed and inform the context about changes by using `ChangeObjectState`. So you must track what user has modified or implement something directly to your entities. For example implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) (if you are using EntityObject based entities this interface should be already implemented).

Comment: Can you show an example (or a link to one) how to inform context that only one value from 15 columns have changed so the update doesn't touch other 14 columns ?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729044/how-can-i-update-a-single-field-from-an-entity-with-entity-framework/3730581#3730581)

Comment: Thanks. Very useful. I saw some article about self-tracking entities with some changes like on this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/09/self-tracking-entities-original-values-and-update-customization.aspx Do you know if it's good idea or should I do it by hand using your way?

Answer (score 6):

If the entity is detached from a context you can't find out what has changed unless you are reloading the original entity from the database or you are using self-tracking entities or manage a tracking somehow yourself.

If you reload the entity you can use `ApplyCurrentValues`:

```
var originalEntity = context.MyEntities.Single(e => e.Id == detachedEntity.Id);
context.MyEntities.ApplyCurrentValues(detachedEntity);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This method marks the properties as modified which have different values between original and detached entity. `SaveChanges` will create an UPDATE statement which includes only those changed properties. If no property did change, `SaveChanges` does nothing.

But you are not completely free from "unnecessary traffic" because you have to load the original entity, you will save an unnecessary UPDATE statement though.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the best way is to implement tracking like @Ladislav Mrnka suggested. This program is supposed to work thru WAN link and having Documents synchronized multiple times which can be small 500kb or large 20MB may be a killer if I decide to reload them from db.